# Why does authentication not go through in MS Teams Bot app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Cannot authenticate user in MS Teams Bot.
[image]

Same works in "Test in webchat" properly:
[image]

Domain added to Teams manifest properly:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.15/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifestVersion": "1.15",
    "id": "a0d93a07-2f63-4569-a651-cf3761859b28",
    "packageName": "com.package.name",
    "name": {
        "short": "NewTest",
        "full": ""
    },
    "developer": {
        "name": "KUKA",
        "mpnId": "",
        "websiteUrl": "https://supportbotkuka.z6.web.core.windows.net/teams_ITSupport_about.html",
        "privacyUrl": "https://supportbotkuka.z6.web.core.windows.net/teams_ITSupport_priv.html",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://supportbotkuka.z6.web.core.windows.net/teams_ITSupport_terms.html"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "CS Logistics TEST app",
        "full": "test app for CS Logistics"
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "outline.png",
        "color": "color.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "conversations",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        },
        {
            "entityId": "about",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "99e82921-96c9-4ec1-83ab-bd05382abc96",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "supportsCalling": false,
            "supportsVideo": false,
            "supportsFiles": true
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "token.botframework.com"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "1e04e5cd-88e1-4522-984d-2bba5e2d37eb",
        "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
    }
}
```

Also recreated AppService, AzureBot in Azure, and setup new Teams app with new manifest version via Developer Portal.
Installed the Teams app directly just form myself, as a personal app.

App registration redirect URIs:
[image]

Also the app registration works fine for other chatbots in our domain. Why not for this one?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to [enable SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview) for your teams bot.

Comment: Same, non SSO authentication works for other Teams bots in the domain. And it worked for this one too so far. So why did it stop working all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the only thing that needed to be changed was to add this line of code to the error handler adapter to the bot code: `base.Use(new TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware(storage, configuration["ConnectionName"]));`[Add code to handle an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-code?tabs=cs1%2Ccs2%2Ccs3%2Ccs4&pivots=bot-app).
And also to add method OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync to Bot like in [sso-quickstart sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/BotConversationSsoQuickstart/Bots/TeamsBot.cs).